# What step am I missing in this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this expression equals $-4k$, but I cannot figure it out. Can anybody please walk me through this step by step?

original expression:
$$1-(2(2k+1)-1)$$

so, my first step is:
$$1-(4k+2-1)$$

Then:
$$1-(4k+1)$$

How does this get to be $-4k$? And why?

Thanks!

Comment: $1-(4k+1)=1-4k-1=-4k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing, or where you are stuck, is in being sure to distribute the negation over the sum (see the expressions in red, below):

$$
\begin{align}
1-(2(2k+1)-1) &= 1 - (4k +2 -1)\\ &= \color{red}{1 - (4k  + 1)}\tag{*} \\ &= \color{red}{ 1 -4k -1}\\ &= -4k
\end{align}
$$

Your work is fine to this point $(*)$. To obtain the next line was just a matter of *distributing the negative sign* over *all of* $(4k+1)$: 
It might help to think of it like multiplying the sum (in parenthes) by $\;-1\,$:
$$
\begin{align}
\color{red}{1 - (4k + 1)} &= 1 + -1(4k+1) \\ &= 1 + -1\cdot 4k + -1\cdot 1\\ &= 1 - 4k - 1 \\ &= -4k
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Not remembering a bunch of old simple algebra is killing me with proofs...

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @user56763: amWhy is fondof killing the problems, always. ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Algebra mistakes are so tricky to get control of! +1

Answer (score 3):

$1-(2(2k+1)-1) = 1-(4k+1) =1-4k-1 = -4k$

The step you are missing is you have to `push' the minus 1 in wards,.e.g., apply distributivity.

Answer (score 3):

You did it correct till end. At the end you got $1-(4k+1)$, but we have always have $$-(a+b)=-a-b$$ So $$(1-(4k+1))=(1-4k-1)=1-1-4k=0-4k=-4k$$